# Double or Embeded Abbreviation (or an abbreviation inside a part of another abbreviation)

Tags: abbreviations

In the abbreviation "MMG", the 1st "M" stands for another abbreviation which is "MBC", while the 2nd "M" stands for "Media" and "G" stands for "Group".

What do we call the 1st "M" (which is an abbreviation already) in the abbreviation "MMG"?!

Is there such a case? If so then what's it called?

Comment: The first M is an abbreviation—MBC shortened to M. MMG is an initialism—the first letters of M + Media + Group pronounced letter-by-letter. See [Abbreviations vs. Acronyms vs. Initialisms](https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/abbreviations/abbreviations-acronyms-and-initialisms-revisited/)

Comment: I know what abbreviations, acronyms and initialisms are, you don't understand my point here! Please read my question again and pay more attention!

Comment: As stated previously, we call the first M in MMG an abbreviation; M is the abbreviation of MMG. It's an abbreviation of an abbreviation.